# Can a moving magnetic field create eddy currents in a conductor ?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

Moving a magnet in and out of a solenoid makes a current flow in the solenoid. I know that a changing magnetic field induces emf in a conductor but what about a moving magnetic field ? Are eddy currents present in the solenoid (above) ?

Comment: What do you mean with above?

Comment: above meaning in the example above which is the movement of a permanent magnet in and out of a solenoid.

Answer (score 0):

Magnetic fields don't move. Fields don't move. A field has a value at every point in space, and those values could change or stay the same.

When you move a permanent magnet, then the magnetic field around it changes and there are induced electric fields.